# Could you give me an example of the function $f(x)$ which is not Riemann integrable but is such that $xf(x)$ is Riemann integrable?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, riemann-integration

I guess this is an easy exercise for analysts but at the moment i do not know of such an example.

So:

> Could you give me an example of the function $f(x)$ which is not Riemann integrable but is such that $xf(x)$ is Riemann integrable?

Comment: $\frac1x$ on $[-1,1]$

Comment: @Mirko Is not that integral $0$ in principal value sense, if that sense is called "principal value"?

Comment: your posted question is not about principal value, but about Riemann integral. At any rate, if you prefer then take $\frac1{|x|}$ on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @Mirko This is a matter of taste, I like to call function integrable even if the integral is $+ \infty$ or $- \infty$, but OK.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not about your preferences, but about Riemann integration, where you need to follow the accepted definitions (they are not a matter of taste, they are adopted once and for all, and the name Riemann integral goes with a very specific definition). If you have a question about something else, or involving additional conditions, you need to state it clearly and/or post it separately.

Comment: @Mirko You are right that I should have posted in the question that I call function integrable if integral is $+ \infty$ or $- \infty$, because that changes the answers to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $f(x)=0$, for $x=0$ and $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ for $x > 0$. Then $f$ isn't integrable on $[0,1]$ and but $xf(x)$ is.